# How to Locate Timestamps of a Subset of a Video

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg, mp4

I have never done any video-based programming before, and although [this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/1044569/get-timestamp-of-a-keyframe-exactly-before-a-given-timestamp-with-ffmpeg) provides a way to do it on the command line, I prefer a programmatic approach, preferably with Python.

I have a bunch of sub-videos. Suppose one of them is called 1234_trimmed.mp4 which is a short segment cut from the original, much-longer video 1234.mp4. **How can I figure out the start and end timestamps of 1234_trimmed.mp4 inside 1234.mp4?**

FYI, the videos are all originally on YouTube anyway ("1234" corresponds to the YouTube video ID) if there's any shortcut that way.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out myself with `cv2`. My strategy was to get the first and last frames of the subvideo and iterate over each frame of the original video, where I compare the current frame's dhash (minimum hamming distance instead of checking for equality in case of resizing and other transformations) against the first and last frames. I'm sure there may be some optimization opportunities but I need this yesterday.

```py
import cv2

original_video_fpath = '5 POPULAR iNSTAGRAM BEAUTY TRENDS (DiY Feather Eyebrows, Colored Mascara, Drippy Lips, Etc)-vsNVU7y6dUE.mp4'
subvideo_fpath = 'vsNVU7y6dUE_trimmed-out.mp4'


def dhash(image, hashSize=8):
    # resize the input image, adding a single column (width) so we
    # can compute the horizontal gradient
    resized = cv2.resize(image, (hashSize + 1, hashSize))
    # compute the (relative) horizontal gradient between adjacent
    # column pixels
    diff = resized[:, 1:] > resized[:, :-1]
    # convert the difference image to a hash
    return sum([2 ** i for (i, v) in enumerate(diff.flatten()) if v])


def hamming(a, b):
    return bin(a^b).count('1')


def get_video_frame_by_index(video_cap, frame_index):
    # get total number of frames
    totalFrames = video_cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)

    if frame_index < 0:
        frame_index = int(totalFrames) + frame_index

    # check for valid frame number
    if frame_index >= 0 & frame_index <= totalFrames:
        # set frame position
        video_cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_index)

    _, frame = video_cap.read()
    return frame


def main():
    cap_original_video = cv2.VideoCapture(original_video_fpath)

    cap_subvideo = cv2.VideoCapture(subvideo_fpath)

    first_frame_subvideo = get_video_frame_by_index(cap_subvideo, 0)
    last_frame_subvideo = get_video_frame_by_index(cap_subvideo, -1)

    first_frame_subvideo_gray = cv2.cvtColor(first_frame_subvideo, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    last_frame_subvideo_gray = cv2.cvtColor(last_frame_subvideo, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    hash_first_frame_subvideo = dhash(first_frame_subvideo)
    hash_last_frame_subvideo = dhash(last_frame_subvideo)

    min_hamming_dist_with_first_frame = float('inf')
    closest_frame_index_first = None
    closest_frame_timestamp_first = None

    min_hamming_dist_with_last_frame = float('inf')
    closest_frame_index_last = None
    closest_frame_timestamp_last = None

    frame_index = 0
    while(cap_original_video.isOpened()):
        frame_exists, curr_frame = cap_original_video.read()

        if frame_exists:
            timestamp = cap_original_video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC) // 1000

            hash_curr_frame = dhash(curr_frame)

            hamming_dist_with_first_frame = hamming(hash_curr_frame, hash_first_frame_subvideo)
            hamming_dist_with_last_frame = hamming(hash_curr_frame, hash_last_frame_subvideo)

            if hamming_dist_with_first_frame < min_hamming_dist_with_first_frame:
                min_hamming_dist_with_first_frame = hamming_dist_with_first_frame
                closest_frame_index_first = frame_index
                closest_frame_timestamp_first = timestamp

            if hamming_dist_with_last_frame < min_hamming_dist_with_last_frame:
                min_hamming_dist_with_last_frame = hamming_dist_with_last_frame
                closest_frame_index_last = frame_index
                closest_frame_timestamp_last = timestamp

            frame_index += 1
        else:
            print('processed {} frames'.format(frame_index+1))
            break

    cap_original_video.release()
    print('timestamp_start={}, timestamp_end={}'.format(closest_frame_timestamp_first, closest_frame_timestamp_last))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

MP4 utilizes relative timestamps. When the file was trimmed the old timestamps were lost, and the new file now begins at time stamp zero.

So the only way to identify where this file may overlap with another file is to use computer vision or perceptual hashing. Both options are too complex to describe in a single stackoverflow answer.

Answer (score -1):

If they were simply `-codec copy`'d, the timestamps should be as they were in the original file. If they weren't, ffmpeg is not the tool for the job. In that case, you should look into other utilities that can find an exactly matching video and audio frame in both files and get the timestamps from there.